# React does not compile/build new files - (after a while!)

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

Hi I am fairly new to React,

And I am at that stage of trying to build my simple good for nothing single page application to learn about how things work.

I am using Min 19, and IntelliJ Ultimate.

I start on the terminal with `create-react-app new-app-7` and I run the application by `npm start`

my `node version` command spits out this information at the moment.
`npm version
{ 'new-app-7': '0.1.0',
  npm: '6.4.1',
  ares: '1.14.0',
  cldr: '32.0.1',
  http_parser: '2.7.1',
  icu: '60.2',
  modules: '57',
  nghttp2: '1.30.0',
  node: '8.10.0',
  openssl: '1.1.0g',
  tz: '2017c',
  unicode: '10.0',
  uv: '1.18.0',
  v8: '6.2.414.50',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }`

Everything works, I create/update a component, stuff happens in the "npm start" terminal window and changes are reflected on the browser. Everything is fan-damn-tastic so far.

After some point the watcher (i don't know which one, it is the default one that comes with create-react-app and react-scripts I guess) stop detecting "new files" But it is not really an update issue, the newly generated files are completely ignored and not even compiled.

For example I create
Component1, Component2, Component3 all fine (very similar components with different text!) and suddenly everything stops working at Component4

I create a completely new project `create-react-app new-app-8` and I can write code for a while normally Comp1, C2, C3, C4, C5 and it again does the same thing at a random point...

Even if I stop the process and run `npm start` manually, the system is completely blind to the new file. I am doing intentional parse errors in this file and no complaints on the compile screen. When I try to import this component to a previously created one I get "Can't resolve" errors.

Despite knowing that it is not a watching issue I installed nodemon, which correctly detects that a new file is created/changed and triggers npm start but again the file is not compiled.

I am thinking there is some sort of cache somewhere that is bugging out after some duration?

The linux mint is also in a vmware but I suppose that should not cause a problem.

I tried googling the problem, thinking it should be a fairly common one but using keywords "watcher" "not compiling" etc diverts me to very wrong alleys.

Anyone has any suggestions? or pointers?

edit 1: tried this to no luck. `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: Are you just creating the components and the watcher doesn't discover it or even when you import the component into another component, the watcher still doesn't discover it?

Comment: I am creating the components and watcher does not discover it AND if I import it to another component I get "cannot resolve `newly-created-but-not-detected-component`"